# Scraping from website list returns a null result based of Xpath

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, xpath, python-requests

So I'm trying to scrape the job listing off this site https://www.dsdambuster.com/careers .

I have the following code:

```
url = "https://www.dsdambuster.com/careers"
page = requests.get(url, verify=False)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
path = '/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[9]/div[1]/div[3]/div[*]/div[1]/a[*]/div/div[1]/div'
 
jobs = tree.xpath(xpath)

for job in jobs:
    Title = (job.text)
    print(Title)
```

not too sure why it wouldnt work...

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 issues here:

1. You are using very bad XPath. It is extremely fragile and not reliable.
   Instead of

```py
'/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[9]/div[1]/div[3]/div[*]/div[1]/a[*]/div/div[1]/div'
```

Please use

```py
'//div[@class="vf-vacancy-title"]'
```

2. You are possibly missing a wait / delay.
   I'm not familiar with the way you are using here, but with Selenium that I do familiar with, you will need to wait for the elements completely loaded before extracting their text contents.